# Matplotlib savefig cuts off pyplot table

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to make some summarizing visualization + statistics of a data column. 
I want to combine two or more subplots with a descriptive table and save the figure locally. 
However, when saving the plot, a part of the table gets cropped.

When I do the following

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

column=np.random.normal(size=10000)
df=pd.DataFrame(column, columns=["Price"])

summary = (
        df.describe()
        .append((df.isnull().sum()/len(df)*100)
        .rename('nans %'))
        .iloc[:,0].to_frame()
        )
fig, (ax_distplot) = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(25, 12))

#Distplot with summarizing table
sns.distplot(df.loc[:,"Price"], hist=True, bins=30, kde=False, ax=ax_distplot)
ax_distplot.set(ylabel='Count')
tab = ax_distplot.table(cellText=np.around(summary.values, decimals=2), 
                        rowLabels=summary.index, 
                        colLabels=summary.columns, loc="right", 
                        bbox=[1.15, .2, 0.25, 0.8])
```

I get:
[image: What it should be]

When saving it locally with the following command

```
plt.savefig("Price.pdf", bbox_inches="tight")
```

Yields:
[image: Cutted off table]

I have tried

```
plt.subplots_adjust(right=0.85)
```

without any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround is to add some pad around the figure. I tried and `pad_inches=1` works well in your example

```
plt.savefig("Price.pdf", bbox_inches="tight", pad_inches=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an error in how the table bounding box is calculated. You may open an issue about it.

In the meantime drawing the canvas manually (and hence twice) solves this.

```
fig.canvas.draw()
plt.savefig("price.png", bbox_inches="tight")
```